# How to use Vuetify from brython

Tags: vuetify.js, brython

Here is a small sample of using Vuetify. How can I correctly translate it into brython ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-carousel
      cycle
      height="400"
      hide-delimiter-background
      show-arrows-on-hover
    >
      <v-carousel-item
        v-for="(slide, i) in slides"
        :key="i"
      >
        <v-sheet
          :color="colors[i]"
          height="100%"
        >
          <v-row
            class="fill-height"
            align="center"
            justify="center"
          >
            <div class="text-h2">
              {{ slide }} Slide
            </div>
          </v-row>
        </v-sheet>
      </v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
  </v-app>
</div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
//https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#server-side-paginate-and-sort
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      colors: [
        'indigo',
        'warning',
        'pink darken-2',
        'red lighten-1',
        'deep-purple accent-4',
      ],
      slides: [
        'First',
        'Second',
        'Third',
        'Fourth',
        'Fifth',
      ],
    }
  },
})

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't correctly translate js part of the code to brython. I expect to get working brython sample with Vuetify.

I saw samples of using pure Vue from brython and I like to see the same with Vuetify, because with Vuetify I can use ready components, just fill new html tags and fill json.

Answer (score -1):

I found. Javascript objects are called through window.
'''

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3/brython.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3/brython_stdlib.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

</head>
<body  onload="brython(1)">
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-carousel
      cycle
      height="400"
      hide-delimiter-background
      show-arrows-on-hover
    >
      <v-carousel-item
        v-for="(slide, i) in slides"
        :key="i"
      >
        <v-sheet
          :color="colors[i]"
          height="100%"
        >
          <v-row
            class="fill-height"
            align="center"
            justify="center"
          >
            <div class="text-h2">
              {{ slide }} Slide
            </div>
          </v-row>
        </v-sheet>
      </v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
  </v-app>
</div>


  <script type="text/python">
#https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#server-side-paginate-and-sort

from browser import document, window

Vue = window.Vue

app = Vue.new({
  'el': '#app',
  'vuetify': window.Vuetify.new(),
  'data': {
      'colors': [
        'indigo',
        'warning',
        'pink darken-2',
        'red lighten-1',
        'deep-purple accent-4'
      ],
      'slides': [
        'First',
        'Second',
        'Third',
        'Fourth',
        'Fifth'
      ]
    }
})


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

'''

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).